# SQL Stored Proc using WHEN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 Tables:  1st: Equipment, the 2nd: Control_Log
The Equipment table stores SetId & Status fields of scanners.
The Control_Log table stores only Scanners being used for the day.

How do I update my Equipment Table [EStatus] field to 'In-Use' 
    for each Scanner being used in Table: Control_Log
    obviously the code below does not work.

I have:

```
@Scan nvarchar(4)

UPDATE [dbo].[Equipment]
SET    status  = 'In-Use'
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT SCAN1, SCAN2, SCAN3 FROM [dbo].[Control_Log])
AND    [SetID] = @Scan
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perform an update join like

```
UPDATE
    A
SET
    status  = 'In-Use'
FROM  [dbo].[Equipment] A
    JOIN Control_Log B ON A.SetID = B.scan1
OR A.SetID = B.scan2
OR A.SetID = B.scan3
WHERE A.[SetID] = @Scan;
```

Comment: @Sepa, consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would always set the EStatus value to 'In-Use' based on the SetID matching the @Scan value, as the EXISTS part would always be true.

-- Added test values to the Control_Log table...
--INSERT INTO Control_Log
--VALUES('1','12','4')

DECLARE @Scan nvarchar(4);

SET @Scan = 1;

-- This will reset all EStatus values back to NULL...
UPDATE  Equipment
SET     EStatus = NULL;

-- Use this query to update using the @Scan parameter...
UPDATE  e
SET     e.EStatus  = 'In-Use'
FROM    Equipment AS e
WHERE   e.SetID = @Scan
    AND EXISTS
        (SELECT     c.SCAN1, c.SCAN2, c.SCAN3 
         FROM       Control_Log c
         WHERE      c.SCAN1 = e.SetID
         OR         c.SCAN2 = e.SetID
         OR         c.SCAN3 = e.SetID)

-- Use this query to update all Equipment records
-- that match values in the Control_Log,
-- without using a parameter...
--SELECT    e.*
UPDATE  e
SET     e.EStatus = 'In-Use'
FROM    Equipment AS e
WHERE   EXISTS
        (SELECT     c.SCAN1, c.SCAN2, c.SCAN3 
         FROM       Control_Log c
         WHERE      c.SCAN1 = e.SetID
         OR         c.SCAN2 = e.SetID
         OR         c.SCAN3 = e.SetID)

SELECT * FROM Control_Log

SELECT * FROM Equipment

[Image of above queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nka7t.jpg)

[Equipment values after update query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WopEq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review the following article on how to write a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer